# Error in evalSummaryFunction Caret R

Tags: r, r-caret

I have this data set

```
 'data.frame':  212300 obs. of  19 variables:

 $ FL_DATE_MDD_MMDD     : int  101 101 101 101 101 101 101 101 101 101 ...

 $ FL_DATE              : int  1012013 1012013 1012013 1012013 1012013 1012013 1012013 1012013 1012013 1012013 ...

 $ UNIQUE_CARRIER       : Factor w/ 13 levels "9E","AA","AS",..: 11 10 2 5 8 9 11 10 10 10 ...

 $ DEST                 : Factor w/ 150 levels "ABE","ABQ","ALB",..: 111 70 82 8 8 31 110 44 53 80 ...

 $ DEST_CITY_NAME       : Factor w/ 148 levels "Akron, OH","Albany, NY",..: 107 61 96 9 9 29 106 36 97 78 ...

 $ ROUNDED_TIME         : int  451 451 551 551 551 551 551 551 551 551 ...

 $ CRS_DEP_TIME         : int  500 520 600 600 600 600 600 600 602 607 ...

 $ DEP_DEL15            : Factor w/ 2 levels "No","Yes": 1 2 1 1 1 1 1 2 1 1 ...

 $ CRS_ARR_TIME         : int  746 813 905 903 855 815 901 744 901 841 ...

 $ Conditions           : Factor w/ 28 levels "Blowing Snow",..: 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 ...

 $ Dew.PointC           : num  -14.4 -14.4 -14.4 -14.4 -14.4 -14.4 -14.4 -14.4 -14.4 -14.4 ...

 $ Events               : Factor w/ 10 levels "","Fog","Fog-Rain",..: 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 ...

 $ Humidity             : int  68 68 71 71 71 71 71 71 71 71 ...

 $ Sea.Level.PressurehPa: num  1021 1021 1022 1022 1022 ...

 $ TemperatureC         : num  -9.4 -9.4 -10 -10 -10 -10 -10 -10 -10 -10 ...

 $ VisibilityKm         : num  16.1 16.1 16.1 16.1 16.1 16.1 16.1 16.1 16.1 16.1 ...

 $ Wind.Direction       : Factor w/ 18 levels "Calm","East",..: 9 9 7 7 7 7 7 7 7 7 ...

 $ WindDirDegrees       : int  320 320 330 330 330 330 330 330 330 330 ...

 $ Wind.SpeedKm.h       : num  20.4 20.4 13 13 13 13 13 13 13 13 ...

 - attr(*, "na.action")=Class 'omit'  Named int [1:22539] 3 32 45 87 94 325 472 548 949 1333 ...

  .. ..- attr(*, "names")= chr [1:22539] "3" "32" "45" "87" ...
```

and when I execute the following in Caret

```
plsFit3x10cv <-train(DEP_DEL15~., data=training3, method="pls",trControl=ctrl,metric="ROC",preProc=c("center","scale"))
```

I get the error:

Error in evalSummaryFunction(y, wts = weights, ctrl = trControl, lev = classLevels,  : 
  train()'s use of ROC codes requires class probabilities. See the classProbs option of trainControl()

Answer (score 0):

The answer to your question is in the error message. It says `train()'s use of ROC codes requires class probabilities. See the classProbs option of trainControl()`. So, you need to use `classProbs = TRUE` in `trainControl()`, and of course, set `summaryFunction = twoClassSummary` (if you have not already done so).

```
ctrl <- trainControl(method = "repeatedcv", 
                     repeats = 3, 
                     classProbs = TRUE,
                     summaryFunction = twoClassSummary)

plsFit3x10cv <-train(DEP_DEL15~., 
                     data=training3, 
                     method="pls",
                     preProc=c("center","scale"),
                     metric="ROC",
                     trControl=ctrl)
```